# 400 / 500 error adding worklog in Jira REST API

Tags: c#, .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I am ready to bang my head off a brick wall so would greatly appreciate any input on this.
I am getting the above mentioned errors when I try to add a new worklog.
The code to try and add the worklog....

```
// convert worklog to json string
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = serializer.Serialize(worklog);

// set up the web request
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(baseUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = method;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

// Authorize user
string base64Credentials =     GetEncodedCredentials(_currentEmployeeUsername_currentEmployeePassword);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
writer.Write(data);
}

// return the response
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

The worklog object I am serializing is as follows...

```
public class WorkLog
{
    public string comment;

    public DateTime started;

    public string timeSpent;
}
```

The above code gave me a **500 Internal Server** error.
I've had a browse around lots of questions asked previously and guessed the issue was with the data I am sending. So I've tried a number of variations, one example which had been marked as an answer suggested the following:

```
"{\"self\": \"http://myservername/rest/api/latest/issue/24469/worklog\", \"author\": {\"self\": \"http://myservername/rest/api/latest/issue/24469/worklog\", \"name\": \"cbourke\", \"displayName\": \"cbourke\", \"active\": false }, \"updateAuthor\": { \"self\": \"http://myservername/rest/api/latest/issue/24469/worklog\", \"name\": \"cbourke\", \"displayName\": \"cbourke\", \"active\": false }, \"comment\": \"Testing.\", \"started\": \"2012-02-15T17:34:37.937-0600\", \"timeSpent\": \"3h 20m\", \"timeSpentSeconds\": 12000, \"id\": \"1234\"}"
```

So I replaced my 'data' with this (adding in my own values). And that gives me the **400 Bad request** error.
I would be eternally grateful for suggestions as to what I can do to rectify this. I am sure I am doing something silly here but cannot seem to find it / figure it out.

Thanking you!

Comment: look at the server error logs for details about the 500. that should be your first stop anytime there is a 500.

Comment: Thanks Marc, would you be able to point me in the right direction to find the logs? I had a search around already but could not find anything useful.

Comment: no idea. depends on your particular webserver. e.g. iis and apache keep things in totally different places.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that but thanks. Had a root around and couldn't find anything. I DID however, find a way to get this to work. Like I said, I was playing around with strings for the data (I had a feeling that was the issue) and if I pass the following, I can add / update a log. string data = "{\"timeSpent\": \"1h 30m\", \"started\": \"2015-09-01T10:30:18.932+0530\", \"comment\": \"testing\"}"; I have a feeling the date format is an issue. Will dig more and see what I can come up with.